# Why function doesn't work with that use of pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

I don't know how i should use pointer, to take value of "win" in function main from function spr(). Should I define one more var for example resullt and write it as:

```
bool *result;
result=&win;
```

The whole program should work fine, but I can't manage with using pointers.
What do you think? Thanks for help!

```
bool spr(char arr[3][3], bool *win)
{
    if(arr[0][0]==arr[0][1] && arr[0][1]==arr[0][2] || arr[1][0]==arr[1][1] && arr[1][1] ==arr[1][2] || arr[2][0]==arr[2][1] && arr[2][1]==arr[2][2])
    {
        *win=true;      

    }
    else if(arr[0][0]==arr[1][0] && arr[1][0]==arr[2][0] || arr[0][1]==arr[1][1] && arr[1][1]==arr[2][1] || arr[0][2]==arr[1][2] && arr[1][2]==arr[2][2])
    {
        *win=true;

    }
    else if(arr[0][0]==arr[1][1] && arr[1][1]==arr[2][2] || arr[0][2]==arr[1][1] && arr[1][1]==arr[2][0])
    {
        *win=true;

    }
    return *win;
    printf("wygrales");
}

int main()
{
    char arr[3][3]={{' ',' ',' '},{' ',' ',' '}};
    int x1,x2,y1,y2;
    int kolejka=0;
    printf("GRA W KOLKO I KRZYZYYK!");
    Sleep(2000);
    system("cls");


    while((&win)!=true || kolejka <=9)
    {
        printf(" KOLKO: Wprowadz wspodlrzedne: \n");
        scanf("%d",&x1);
        scanf("%d",&y1);
        arr[x1][y1]='O';

        spr(arr,&win);
        wypisz(arr);

        printf("KRZYZYK: Wprowadz wspolrzedne:\n ");
        scanf("%d",&x2);
        scanf("%d",&y2);
        arr[x2][y2]='X';

        spr(arr,&win);
        wypisz(arr);
        kolejka++;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to define `bool win = false;` in `main()`, and change `while((&win)!=true || kolejka <=9)` --> `while(win != true || kolejka <=9)`. The `wypisz()` function has not been defined.

Comment: You can declare win global. Then everything will be easy.

Comment: @purec -- global variables are not a good solution; it is bad style to use globals unless absolutely necessary, and here a global is not called for.

Comment: @David Bowling. No, sir, it's a stereotype. When something needs to be shared between main and service routines in a small program with definite and precise goals and methods global variables are obvious and right decision. Why would you double them other way? What's the point?

Comment: @purec -- It is not a "stereotype", it is good style to avoid global variables when they aren't needed; of course there are exceptions, but this isn't one of them. You certainly don't need to spur learners into defining a global variable every time another solution isn't immediately apparent. But if you believe that globals are the answer here, put it in an answer below.

Comment: @David Bowling, this is exactly the case. Unfortunately I have no time right now to post extensive answer and my English is not that good. But I advise you and Kamila to have a look at rogue source code(you can easily find it). File init.c consists all of global variable definitions and initializations! "bool playing = TRUE, running = FALSE, wizard = FALSE;" etc... What can I add to this?... What do we have here is exactly the same in miniature. So, why not use globals? Agressive public education makes it's job: they don't use globals because they are evil (like Saddam Hussein) ><

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185360/discussion-between-purec-and-david-bowling).

Comment: @purec -- I never said that globals should never be used. Globals should not be used cavalierly, and you suggested a solution using globals to a learner in a program that does not need them. [If you choose to use a global variable, have a good reason.](https://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/break-points/4025723/A-pox-on-globals)

Answer (score 0):

you do not declare win anywhere. BTW the `printf("wygrales");` will never be reached as you return from the function before it.

```
int main()
{
  ...
  bool win = false;

  ...
  while(!win || kolejka <=9)
  ...
```

But you do not need to pass pointer to win to the function `spr`. Just return true if your long `if`s are ok or false at the end of the function. You do not this pointer at all.

You will need to change

`spr(arr,&win);` -> `win = spr(arr);`

and declare win in the main as in my first part of the answer;